# Add css to parent element by javascript

Tags: javascript, css, parent-child

i style `<a>` with background color... but when i have `<img>` in the link tag, the background color is visible under/near/anywhere-of the image.

so, i would like to style those links which contain images (background: none) but as css4 parent-element does not show up yet in any browser (a < img). How can i do it with javascript ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: So, any link that has an image should have no background?

Comment: @crush : yes, any link ! Lex Podgorny has answered here below, i use his jquery code which works... now, i just try to figure out how to disappear the bg color even before page loads (my question is in the comment of Lex Podgorny's answer)

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can do:

```
$('a:has(img)').css('background-color', 'transparent');
```

With straight up javascript I would try:

```
// Check not only immediate children but all descendants recursively
function hasImgChild(oElement) {
    if (oElement.tagName == 'img') { return true; }
    for (var n=0; n<oElement.childNodes.length; n++) {
        if (hasImgChild(oElements.childNodes[n])) { return true; }
    } 
    return false;
}

// Get all <a> tag dom references
var aLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Loop through all <a> tags and if any of them
// Have <img> descendants, set background-color css property to 'transparent'
for (var n=0; n<aLinks.length; n++) {
    if (hasImgChild(aLinks[n])) {
        aLinks[n].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the built in `.contains` function?

Comment: @scrblnrd3 Please post a reference to `.contains` documentation and suggest where exactly I should use it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, jquery works... only one problem, the background colors disappear only after one second... i use `$(document).ready(function(){`, maybe is there another way that the colors do not appear even for a second ?

Comment: Then I would suggest doing the reverse. Instead of clearing bgcolor on ready, add it to elements that don't have the image inside. Of course, you'd have to edit your styles as well.

Comment: Like so: `$('a:not(:has(img))').css('background-color', 'yellow');`

Comment: The best solution, however, would be to define two different css classes for these that do have image and those that don't. Not sure if this is an option for you. But this way there would be no lag at all.

Comment: Yes, you are right, because your last solution (to make the opposite) does not work for me because i have links which do not have bg image but which should not have bg img either... i must better to give a class tag to those links which have images, in that case css will be enough... thanks your interest anyway !!!

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript you can do

```
elements=document.getElementsByTagName("transparent");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    el=elements[i];
    if(el.contains("img")){
        el.style.backgroundColor="white";
    }
}
```